# HTML5 Canvas - text not written on first load

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've being doing a technical test for a recruiter and have come across and extremely annoying bug with html5/canvas/javascript.

The problem only occurs intermittently and usually only on the first load of the page.

The images all load ok but the 3 character code only loads when I reload the page manually.

I've tried adding callbacks and even a setTimeout but there appeasr to be something happening on the initial load but I can't trap it.

Here's my code:

```
function Rectangle() {

    this.w = 111;
    this.h = 111;
    this.font_color = "white";
    this.font_family = "18pt Novecentowide";

}

Icon.prototype = new Rectangle();

function Icon(data) {

    this.code = data['code'];
    this.bg_color = data['bg_color'];
    this.x = data['x'];
    this.y = data['y'];
    this.code_x = data['code_x'];
    this.code_y = data['code_y'];
    this.icon_src = data['icon_src'];
    this.icon_x = data['icon_x'];
    this.icon_y = data['icon_y'];

    this.drawIcon = function () {

        // setup canvas
        var c = document.getElementById("canvasId");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

        // draw rectangle
        ctx.fillStyle = this.bg_color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);

        // apply icon
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = this.icon_src;

        var icon_x = this.icon_x;
        var icon_y = this.icon_y;

        // get text values
        var font_color = this.font_color;
        var font_family = this.font_family;
        var code = this.code;
        var code_x = this.code_x;
        var code_y = this.code_y;

        img.onload = function () {
        // Once the image has finished loading, draw the 
        // image and then the text.

            function DrawScreen() {
                ctx.drawImage(img, icon_x, icon_y);
            }

            DrawScreen();

        };

        function DrawText() {
            ctx.fillStyle = font_color;
            ctx.font = font_family;
            ctx.fillText(code, code_x, code_y);
        }

        DrawText();

    }

}

var icon1 = new Icon({code: "ABC", bg_color: "c64918", x: 0, y: 0, code_x: 13, code_y: 98, icon_src: "images/shape_icon.png", icon_x: 0, icon_y: 0 });

var icon2 = new Icon({code: "DEF", bg_color: "d37724", x: 195, y: 0, code_x: 208, code_y: 98, icon_src: "images/shape_icon.png", icon_x: 195, icon_y: 0 });

var icon3 = new Icon({code: "GHI", bg_color: "556a70", x: 0, y: 151, code_x: 13, code_y: 249, icon_src: "images/hand_icon.png", icon_x: 0, icon_y: 151 });

var icon4 = new Icon({code: "JKL", bg_color: "55777f", x: 195, y: 151, code_x: 208, code_y: 249, icon_src: "images/hand_icon.png", icon_x: 195, icon_y: 151 });

var icon5 = new Icon({code: "MNO", bg_color: "68a03d", x: 0, y: 303, code_x: 13, code_y: 400, icon_src: "images/dollar_icon.png", icon_x: 0, icon_y: 303 });

icon1.drawIcon();

icon2.drawIcon();

icon3.drawIcon();

icon4.drawIcon();

icon5.drawIcon();
```

Can anyone shed some light on why this is happening.

Link to demo is: http://www.mpwa.co/html5

Any help would be very much appreciated.

---

Resolved the problem.

I wasn't checking to see if the document had loaded and so the first attempt at drawing on the canvas was failing.

Basics!!

Here's the key part of the working code...

---

function init() {

```
icon1.drawIcon();

icon2.drawIcon();

icon3.drawIcon();

icon4.drawIcon();

icon5.drawIcon();
```

}

var readyStateCheckInterval = setInterval(function () {

```
if (document.readyState === "complete") {

    init();

    clearInterval(readyStateCheckInterval);

}
```

}, 10);

---

Comment: On the initial load, the image is not yet cached, so it ends up being drawn AFTER you draw the text, effectively covering it.

Answer (score 2):

You should do it like this:

```
    img.onload = function () {
    // Once the image has finished loading, draw the 
    // image and then the text.           
        DrawScreen();
        DrawText();
    };
    function DrawScreen() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, icon_x, icon_y);
    }
    function DrawText() {
        ctx.fillStyle = font_color;
        ctx.font = font_family;
        ctx.fillText(code, code_x, code_y);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Shmiddty.I already tried that along with several other solutions provided online and my own attempts at using anonymous callbacks. It turns out that the issue was that the page (document) hadn't loaded and so it was failing on the first load. I'm now checking to see if the page has loaded before attempting any drawing on the canvas and it works perfectly. Thanks for your reply though.